# Windows Shell Script: Can't make string substitution working in subroutine

Tags: windows, string, cmd, substitution, subroutine

Greetings dear Experts!

Could you please advice me on how to cope with the problem:

```
@echo off
cls

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

path=%CD%;%path% 

set NumberOfPages=553
rem set /A MaxFileIndex=%Counter% - 1
set MaxFileIndex=1

del Output.txt

for /l %%i in (0,1,%MaxFileIndex%) do call :GenerateFileList %%i
goto :eof


::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:GenerateFileList
::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set CurrentFileName="File(%1).txt"
echo !CurrentFileName:"=! > Output.txt
goto :eof

::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:eof
::::::::::::::::::::::::::
endlocal
```

This code echoes on the screen instead of writing to "ExtractedLinks.txt". What is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is that the Windows CMD language is possibly the worst scripting language ever.

Comment: @Joe: No it isn't. Someone not having any idea how to use it is the problem here. @Andrey: Why would you expect it to write to "ExtractedLinks.txt"? You didn't tell it to do any such thing, based on what you posted. Instead, try and explain what it is you're hoping to accomplish; you've only given about 10% of the info people would need in order to even try to help you.

Comment: @ken, yes it is. one can know how to use it, and use it well, but the code that are produced will be ugly, hard to read and often times, inefficient. Hard to read and ugly because 1) syntax, unnecessary characters for syntax eg double % for variables. 2) lack of programming features makes one have to do workarounds producing more unnecessary code. Inefficient because one doesn't have enough programming control.

Comment: ghostdog: it has its quirks but so has every language. This one just happens to have more than many others. Still if you know what you do and are fairly proficient then reading the code still tells you what it does, regardless how ugly it looks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Output.txt not ExtractedLinks.txt:

```
set c=!CurrentFileName:"=!
echo %c% > Output.txt
```

Also, unless you are doing something else in the for loop, you probably want to append instead of overwriting:

```
echo %c% >> Output.txt
```

And if you really want the filename to be ExtractedLinks.txt just change it.

```
echo %c% >> ExtractedLinks.txt
```